# Material 3 Chip, Can't remove outline on InputChip Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, material3

I wanted to create an InputChip Widget that looked the this (The red circle).
[image: screenshot from figma]
[M3 Official Figma](https://www.figma.com/community/file/1035203688168086460)

With This code, I can get the chip circled in blue:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InputChip(
    label: const Text('tag'),
    onDeleted: () {},
  );
}
```

By adding some parameters I can change the color:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InputChip(
    label: const Text('tag'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue[100],
    onDeleted: () {},
  );
}
```

[image: screenshot of my widget]

But I can't remove the outline.

I have tried changing the `selected` parameter to `true` but this creates a check mark I don't want:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InputChip(
    label: const Text('tag'),
    selected: true,
    onDeleted: () {},
  );
}
```

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the implementation of [`InputChip`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_chip.dart), the border style is controlled by the value of `isSelected`:

```dart
@override
BorderSide? get side => !isSelected
  ? isEnabled
    ? BorderSide(color: _colors.outline)
    : BorderSide(color: _colors.onSurface.withOpacity(0.12))
  : const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent);
```

From the source code it seems like there are no other way to achieve the exact combination of border style and background color like that, so you just have to enable `selected` and disable `showCheckmark` like this:

```dart
InputChip(
  // ...
  selected: true,
  showCheckmark: false,
)
```

---

**Note:** It is also possible to set `side` to `BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)`, but then we have to set the background color manually too. The background color used when the chip is selected is taken from a private method in [`RawChip`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/chip.dart) called `_getBackgroundColor`, which make this a more complicated solution.

Comment: Thank you very much! I failed to notice the `showCheckmark` parameter :(